# scrbook - How to add one horizontal line above and one below the chapter-entry without (!) using titlesec?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script, rules, scrbook

I want to add one horizontal line above and one below the chapter-entry as well.

---

**Before using the `scrbook`-class, I used this simple solution made by `titlesec`-package:**

```
\newpagestyle{headrules}{
    \headrule

    % for twosided layout, use:
    \sethead[\thepage][\chaptertitle][]                 % even pages (left side of book)
    {\chaptertitle}{\sectiontitle}{\thepage}            % odd pages (right side of book)

    % for onesided layout, use:
    % \sethead{\thechapter. \chaptertitle}{}{\thepage}  % in this case, the document only has odd pages
}
```

---

**Working minimum example:**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontfamily{pag}\Large\bfseries}{\titlerule[4pt]\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{5pt}{\large}[{\titlerule[2pt]}]
\titleformat{\section}{\fontfamily{pag}\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{5pt}{\normalsize}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\fontfamily{pag}\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{5pt}{\normalsize}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{20pt}{10pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{20pt}{5pt}

\newpagestyle{headrules}{
    \headrule

    % for twosided layout, use:
    \sethead[\thepage][\chaptertitle][]                 % even pages (left side of book)
    {\chaptertitle}{\sectiontitle}{\thepage}            % odd pages (right side of book)

    % for onesided layout, use:
    % \sethead{\thechapter. \chaptertitle}{}{\thepage}  % in this case, the document only has odd pages
}

\setlength{\headheight}{1.1\baselineskip}               % adjusting the height of head

\pagestyle{headrules}                                   % use this style instead of \pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

So, the question now is: How can I solve this **without** using the `titlesec`-package anymore? Using `titlesec` together with a KOMA-class is not recommended, and I prefer to use the `scrbook`-class instead of `book` because of those many great advantages (for example `addchap` and others)...

Do I have to change the pagestyle `plain`-format for this?

Thank you very much for your help!

---

**The following solution from clemens for separating `\chapters` and `\addchaps` seems to make sense, but it doesn't work in the following minimal-example (don't know why):**

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{%
    \ifnumbered{chapter}
    {\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}\par\vspace*{-4pt}}
    {}%
}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{%
    \ifnumbered{chapter}
    {\vspace*{-4pt}\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}\par\vspace{\baselineskip}}
    {}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Experimental chapter-entry}

\addchap{Experimental addchap-entry}

\end{document}
```

---

It doesn't matter if there's a numbered `\chapter` or an unnumbered `\addchap` - either the selected line is existent or absent in both selectors...

Is there any mistake in my line of thought?

---

**Solution:** Upgrading to KOMA-Script v3.18 brought the solution for me, too! Thank you very much clemens and all the others who were helping me!

Thanks a lot for your patient help!

Comment: It is a wellknown fact that KOMA classes and `titlesec` should not used together (And no, `fancyhdr` is no good idea with KOMA as well)

Comment: Of course, this is a well known fact! But thanks a lot for your hint, I've changed the subject and explanatory text a bit...

Comment: The `scrpage2` package is outdated. Use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead.

Comment: I would use `\chapterheadstartvskip` and `\chapterheadendvskip` to add the lines. (And it is imho a not so well known fact, that it is difficult to create fancy sectioning commands only with KOMA-tools. )

Comment: See http://www.komascript.de/node/486

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm sorry: I saw your comment only after I posted my answer. If you want to add your comment as an answer I'll gladly remove mine!

Comment: @Dave I don't see how the pagestyle (which is the style of header and footer) should affect the design of the chapter titles?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks a lot for your advice! I've tried it out using the commands suggested from you `\chapterheadstartvskip` and `\chapterheadendvskip`. Unfortunately, however, `chapterheadendvskip` doesn't accept the `\rule`-command. Only `\chapterheadstartvskip` takes it as desired...

Comment: @Andrew Swann: Thank you very much for your help, too! I've tried it out using the proposed code from you. It seemed to work fine, but I ran into some problems by adjusting the space between the `\rule` below and the chapters name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

With KOMA-Script Version 3.19 or newer there is another possibility: you can redefine the new command `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` to insert the lines:

```
\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\rule{\textwidth}{#1}}
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{}{\titlerule[4pt]\par}%
  #2#3\titlerule[2pt]%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  chapterprefix=true
]{scrbook}[2015/09/29]% needs version 3.19 or newer

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{chapter}

\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\rule{\textwidth}{#1}}
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{}{\titlerule[4pt]\par\nobreak}%
  #2#3\par\nobreak\titlerule[2pt]%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Experimental chapter-entry}
\blindtext
\addchap{Experimental addchap-entry}
\blindtext
\chapter*{Experimental chapter*-entry}
\blindtext
\addchap*{Experimental addchap*-entry}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

If this should also work with option `chapterprefixline=false` add the following lines to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}\par\nobreak\titlerule%
}
\makeatother
```

---

**Original answer**

If the line above the chapter heading should only be inserted if the `chapterprefix` is written you could insert this line in `\chapterformat`. This works also for `\chapter*` and `\addchap*`.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt,
  afterskip=1\baselineskip
]{chapter}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{#1}\par}
\preto\chapterformat{\IfUsePrefixLine{\vspace{-\baselineskip}\titlerule[4pt]}{}}
\preto\chapterheadendvskip{\titlerule[2pt]}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Experimental chapter-entry}
\blindtext
\addchap{Experimental addchap-entry}
\blindtext
\chapter*{Experimental chapter*-entry}
\blindtext
\addchap*{Experimental addchap*-entry}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Despite their name the usual way with KOMA-Script is to redefine `\chapterheadstartvskip` and `\chapterheadendvskip`:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}\par}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}\par\vspace{\baselineskip}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

With slightly altered definitions only number chapters will get the rules. Adding `\vspace*`s at the right place will move the lines closer to the text:

```
\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{%
  \ifnumbered{chapter}
    {\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}\par\vspace*{-4pt}}
    {}%
}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{%
  \ifnumbered{chapter}
    {\vspace*{-4pt}\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}\par\vspace{\baselineskip}}
    {}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! This works actually perfect! There are only two more things: 1.) Like in the advice from Andrew Swann, I can't adjust the space between the chapters name and the `\rule`. I've tried to set `\rule[2mm]{\linewidth}`, but this does only move the existing text below the line, but not the line itself... 2.) How can I set making the top `\rule` only to "real/original" chapter-headlines, but not to `\addchap`-headlines? The foreword, table of content, acronymslist e.g. only use `\addchap`-headlines, and they should not get the top line (for those only line below).

Comment: @Dave Do you mean between the first rule and the text or between the text and the second rule? Anyway, some `\vspace*` in the right place should do. With `\ifnumbered{chapter}{<true>}{<false>}` within the redefinition you can add the rules only for numbered chapters if placing them in the `<true>` branch

Comment: ... or should I poste a new question because of that: "How to select only "real" `\chapter`-headlines except `\addchap`-headlines simultaneously?"

Comment: Thank you very much for your great support! The spaces are customized now! The `\vspace*`-command has been at the wrong place during my experiment indeed, it has to be placed before `\noindent` and everything works fine now! Furthermore I've tried to set `\ifnumbered{chapter}{\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}\par}}{}`, but this doesn't work. Is there any mistake?

Comment: @Dave `\ifnumbered` needs to be *inside* the definition, see my edited answer

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not sure if there's a mistake, but this minimum-example doesn't work... The lines are existent in every case, they don't matter about numbered/unnumbered: `\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{%
 \ifnumbered{chapter}
 {\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}\par\vspace*{-4pt}}
 {}%
}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{%
 \ifnumbered{chapter}
 {\vspace*{-4pt}\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}\par\vspace{\baselineskip}}
 {}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Experimental chapter-entry}

\addchap{Experimental addchap-entry}

\end{document}`

Comment: @Dave it does for me (KOMA-Script v3.18)

Comment: Okay, upgrading to KOMA-Script v3.18 brought the solution for me, too... Thank you very much!